# Dotnet core publishing to a folder in $PATH

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, path

I am currently setting up a build pipeline for a tooling repository for my company and have the desire to place each of the built tools into $PATH, so that they can be easily executed from powershell. After some googling, I am uncertain about the best way to approach this. What would be nice is a common /bin directory at the root of the repo that all of the tooling publishes to (with dotnet publish), but each resulting build is placed as its own folder, so nuget dependencies for each program can have different versions of whatever they depend on and we don't have to worry about potential binding redirect / version mismatch issues. The thought is that the final folder structure looks like so:

```
/bin
    /app1
        /app1.exe
        /Some.Dep.dll
    /app2
        /app2.exe
        /Some.Dep.dll
```

Is there a way to achieve this by only adding a $PATH entry to `/bin`, or any suggestions on different ways to achieve the same end goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an "AfterPublish" [target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2017) in your .csproj file to run a script that copies the build to your /bin path.

Or create a script that's convenient to access at the root of your repo that executes the built program from the publish directory.

You can also change the [publish directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2017).